# APACHE TOMCAT SERVER NOT STARTING

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, exception

PREVIOUSLY IT SHOW ERROR OF PORT NUMBER. THEN I CHANGE PORT NUMBER BUT AFTER SOME TIME IT GIVE A NEW EXCEPTION FOR STARTING THE SERVER. I ATTACH AND DELETE SERVER FROM ECLIPSE SO MANY TIME FROM ECLIPSE, BUT THE PROBLEM NOT SOLVED.

I ALSO REINSTALL THE ECLIPSE BUT THE EXCEPTION REMAIN SAME.

THE ERROR ON CONSOLE IS:

```
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.5
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 6 2018 21:42:23 UTC
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.5.0
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\kc\eclipse-workspace-new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         I:\software\apatche tomcat server for eclipse\apache-tomcat-9.0.5
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\kc\eclipse-workspace-new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=I:\software\apatche tomcat server for eclipse\apache-tomcat-9.0.5
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\kc\eclipse-workspace-new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=I:\software\apatche tomcat server for eclipse\apache-tomcat-9.0.5\endorsed
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\kc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\kc\Desktop;;.]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1565 ms
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.5
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-common_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_8.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1660)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more

Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    ... 13 more

Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)

Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 17, 2018 11:25:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: post screenshot of error

Comment: Please fix your CAPS LOCK first!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find javax.websocket .jars for use in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906617/where-to-find-javax-websocket-jars-for-use-in-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat throwing javax.websocket.DeploymentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262265/tomcat-throwing-javax-websocket-deploymentexception), also revealed by a simple Google search.

Answer (score 1):

Check your stack trace as this hints towards the problem you're facing. The answer would around this part:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

Seems that you're missing some required dependencies which Tomcat needs to start up. The definition of the exception for Javadoc should provide some more insight towards solving this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html

Are you sure all in all that have all the required jar files Tomcat needs? Also  I would higly suggest to edit your original question, get rid of the caps and resolve all the phrasing problems in order to make it more readable.

Comment: (This looks helpful, but I tend to encourage meta-advice to be posted separately as a comment. This is because the OP, or someone else, will hopefully resolve the problems with the post, leaving the answer with out-of-date information that is not useful to its future readership).

Comment: I would have done so, but the comment section does not allow for many characters and most importantly it does not allow (or I haven't been able to find how to do it yet) for correct code syntax.

Comment: according  to you which jar file associated to tomcat.tell me